# getContentResolver returning null for ContactsContract.Contacts

Tags: android, contacts, android-contentresolver, contactscontract

Calling an Activity from Main Activity , the Activity call CONTENT_URI through Intent

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

OnActivityResult i am trying to get id,contact name and phone but the Query Cursor was returning null

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String cNumber="";
    switch (requestCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  cr.query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String hasPhone =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        Cursor phones =cr.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,
                                null, null);
                        phones.moveToFirst();
                        cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                    }
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    Log.i("name",name);
                    Log.i("nameno", cNumber);
                   // arrayList.clear();
                    for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size(); i++)
                    {
                        String fromlist=arrayList.get(i).toString();
                        String addedtolist=name +"-" + cNumber;
                        if(fromlist.equals(addedtolist))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Conatct already exists. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            isExists=1;
                        }
                    }
                    if(isExists==0)
                    {
                        arrayList.add(name + "-" + cNumber);
                        lstContacts.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        writeToFile(name + "-" + cNumber, "_ShareConatcts.txt");
                       sharecontact(android_id,name,cNumber,1);
                    }
                    isExists=0;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The above command was working fine couple of days back but suddenly started giving null, it does not even throw any error. While debugging cursor C returns null.

Comment: I am not sure what happened, but i recalled the steps i did while testing the app, i added the phone contact no to the contact list and then deleted it, that is when the problem started.I tested the app on other devices and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Is the only one contact available in your contact book? If so, After deleting the number from your contact book, how can you get the contact data?

Comment: Did you got it? I'm having a similar problem, was working and now it returns null.